# Uninstalling UAP app that was installed in different location

Tags: windows, uninstall

I have a problem. I can't uninstall Adobe XD CC, which I installed in a custom drive and now can no longer uninstall. Is there a way to remove it from the UAP package list?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See [Use the Creative Cloud Cleaner Tool to solve installation problems](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/cc-cleaner-tool-installation-problems.html).

The tool can be downloaded [from Adobe](https://download.adobe.com/pub/adobe/SupportTools/Cleaner/win/AdobeCreativeCloudCleanerTool.exe).
Run it as Administrator and follow onscreen instructions to choose the operation
to execute:

[image]

Comment: I tried that but does not solve the problem, its like the problem is the app is still amongs the list of installed apps of UWP package manager while the drive it was installed to is no more

Comment: What do you do to see that the package is still installed?

Comment: i see it when i type the appx getpackage